# Installation of latest version R for linux

Tags: bash, shell

First I typed

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

after that I got one sources list then I typed

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

then I get the error like this

```
No command 'deb' found, did you mean:
 Command 'derb' from package 'icu-devtools' (main)
 Command 'deb3' from package 'quilt' (main)
 Command 'debc' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'dwb' from package 'dwb' (universe)
 Command 'xdeb' from package 'xdeb' (universe)
 Command 'debi' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'dab' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
deb: command not found
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installation of R](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223153/installation-of-r)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal and the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add the line below at the end of the file

   ```
   deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
   ```
3. Save & Close
4. Add the public key

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 06F90DE5381BA480
   ```
5. Update your repository information

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
6. Install

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-base
   ```

Other ways in my anwer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/655307/367165)