# Installation of R

Tags: linux-mint, gpg, r

I want to know about how to install the latest version of R for linux mint

First I tried the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then I typed:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480
```

I got an error message like this:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.hgkQKUHLAd --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480
gpg: requesting key 381BA480 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

After that I tried:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Then I got another error message like this:

```
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Please tell about my problem

Comment: Dirk has recent versions of R packaged for Debian. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/. Also https://wiki.debian.org/R. This should work for Mint too. You might have to rebuild them. Also, post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`, please. And in the question, not a comment. The gpg thing looks like it might be a network error. Try again.

Comment: AFAIK `R` should be in mint's repositories already: try executing `R` and see for the install suggestion (should be along the line `apt-get r-base`)